# Adding objects from Jsoup to an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to add a bunch of objects (from JSoup) to an array list. For some reason, the objects aren't being added.The JSoup queries are correct because I printed the results as they are added in the for loop. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public List<MainGridItem> fruitItem = new ArrayList<>();


    Thread downloadThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup
                        .connect("http://banana-mango.com/hello.htm")
                        .get();
                Elements fruits = doc.select("p[align=center]");
                for (int i = 0; i < fruits.size(); i++) {
                    MainGridItem gr = new MainGridItem(fruits.get(i).select("img").attr("abs:src"),fruits.get(i).text().trim(),fruits.get(i).select("a").attr("abs:href"));
                    //System.out.println(gr.getStuff+gr.getMore+gr.getAgain);
                    fruitItem.add(gr);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    downloadThread.start();
```

Comment: How you know `the objects aren't being added` ? because you are adding all items inside Thread so need to wait until Thread execution is not completed to access item using `fruitItem`

Comment: System.out.println(fruitItem .size());  <-- yields 0. What do you mean I have to wait until Thread execution is not completed?

Comment: Use `System.out.println(fruitItem .size());` line inside `run()` then check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are adding the element in `downloadThread` and using the `ArrayList` in `Ui` Thread . So, there is synchronization problem in you code .

If you simply want to over com that, you can do like(pseudo code only)

```
 public List<MainGridItem> fruitItem = new ArrayList<>();
    Handler handler = new Handler();


        Thread downloadThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup
                            .connect("http://banana-mango.com/hello.htm")
                            .get();
                    Elements fruits = doc.select("p[align=center]");
                    for (int i = 0; i < fruits.size(); i++) {
                        MainGridItem gr = new MainGridItem(fruitItem.get(i).select("img").attr("abs:src"),fruitItem.get(i).text().trim(),fruitItem.get(i).select("a").attr("abs:href"));
                        //System.out.println(gr.getStuff+gr.getMore+gr.getAgain);
                        fruitItem.add(gr);
                    }
               handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Access your arrayList Here and do Ui stuff
                    }
                });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        downloadThread.start();
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know threads worked like that. What can I do to synchronize the arraylist in downloadThread and UI thread? I need the objects in my UI thread.

Comment: I have added a code in above answer handler.post() , every thing written in this method will work on Ui thread

Comment: Whoops, missed that somehow. Code works. My grid crashes once I get to the last items but that's a different issue. Thank you very much!